# How to output integers inside a for-loop as hex values to file

Tags: c, for-loop, image-processing, hex, fwrite

Im trying to create a .pam image with some c-code but the fwrite function only writes the ASCII counterpart to the file, not the hex values.

The head of the file needs to be ASCII and the actual image data needs to be just the hex values for rgb and alpha.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE *out;

    out = fopen("C:/Users/entin/Desktop/write.pam", "wb+");

    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to access file.\n");
    } else {

        //everything concerning the head

        //buffer the head to not get an overflow
        unsigned char headbuf[100];
        sprintf(headbuf, "P7\nWIDTH 255\nHEIGHT 255\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n");

        //reduce head to nessesary length so it dosent output useless NULL's
        int len = strlen(headbuf);
        unsigned char head[len];
        sprintf(head, "P7\nWIDTH 255\nHEIGHT 255\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n");

        //write head to file
        fwrite(head, sizeof (head), 1, out);


        //initiating pixel values
        unsigned char buf[8];
        int r = 0; //AA
        int g = 0; //BB
        int b = 0; //CC
        int a = 255; //DD

        //for now just change the red and green values
        for (r = 0; r <= 255; r++) {
            for (g = 0; g <= 255; g++) {

                //coppy pixel data to buffer
                sprintf(buf, "%02X%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b, a);

                //write buffer to head
                fwrite(buf, sizeof (buf), 1, out);
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(out);
    printf("fin");
    getchar();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It outputs the head as I want it but the pixel values are also written in their ASCII values

It outputs ENDHDR\nAABBCCDD

as.
45 4E 44 48 44 52 0A 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44

it should output it like this:
45 4E 44 48 44 52 0A AA BB CC DD

Comment: You code write it correctly I got `00FFCC0001FFCC0002FFCC0003FFCC0`... What are you expecting for the first bytes ?

Comment: `sprintf(buf, "%02X%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b, a);` This formats your byte values as hex numbers. If you want the binary data instead of hex representation, write the value directly.

Comment: If you need spaces between the numbers... um... add spaces in your format string. And why not just use `fprintf()` instead of that `sprintf()`/`fwrite()` thing (That has undefined behavior because the `sprintf()` writes 9 elements to an 8 element char array...

Comment: `unsigned char head[len];` This is not needed. If you have the length of your text, you can use it to write `headbuffer`. No need to copy it again. You are missing a byte for NUL-terminator enyway and the second `sprintf` will write out of bounds. And also using `strcpy` would be less expensive than doing the formatting via `sprintf` a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code and just wrote the values as their ASCII counterpart.

Here is the fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    FILE *out;

    out = fopen("C:/Users/entin/Desktop/write.pam", "wb+");

    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to access file.\n");
    } else {

        //head
        fprintf(out, "P7\nWIDTH 255\nHEIGHT 255\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n");

        //initiating pixel values
        int r = 0; //red
        int g = 0; //green
        int b = 255; //blue
        int a = 255; //alpha

        //for now just change the red and green values
        for (r = 0; r <= 255; r++) {
            for (g = 0; g <= 255; g++) {

                //call the numbers as theirr ASCII counterpart and print them
                fprintf(out, "%c%c%c%c", r, g, b, a);

            }
        }

    }
    fclose(out);
    printf("fin");
    getchar();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here is the first result

[image: red/green variation, blue/alpha fix255]

Comment: yeah i know, have to turn the height and width to 256